# javascript onsubmit() NOT working as expected

Tags: javascript

```
    function trim(str) {
         str.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');
         return str;
     }

   function checknull(str) {
         if (str==null || str==""||isNaN(str)){
        valid=false
        alert("Field must be a number and can not be NULL");
        return valid;
        }
       else
    {
    return true;
    }
}


function checkform(){
valid = true;
var input1=document.form1.TASKID.value;
checknull(trim(input1));
var x=document.main_form.iid.value;
checknull(trim(x));

return valid;
}
```

The above Javascript is NOT working as expected. Whenever, Input is NON-number, alert box is coming, however it continues to do ACTION command. Don't know why.Below is HTML code thats using this Javascript.

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="myaction.cgi" onSubmit="return checkform()">
```

it is checking only one element at a time, when I use second form, the validation is happening fine, when I use firstform(form1) the validation is happening, however, the form continues to execute its action. WHY? am confused. please help

Comment: The checkform method always return true while it should return false if the one of the input is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable scoping issue. Try this:

```
function checknull(str) {
    if (str === null || str == ""|| isNaN(str)) { 
        alert("Field must be a number and can not be NULL");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

function checkform() {
    var valid = true;

    if (valid) {
        var input1=document.form1.TASKID.value;
        valid = checknull(trim(input1));
    }

    if (valid) {
        var x=document.main_form.iid.value;
        valid = checknull(trim(x));
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to your question, but when I had similar problem I solved it in a different way.
What I did is onkeypress I called a function that would remove everything that is not a digit from the passed field. So every time a user would type anything but a digit in the field, the function would instantly remove that character.
After that on submit I only had to check if the field is blank or not.

Not sure if you want to do it this way, but it works very well.